# Heroku doesn't find assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets

I've tried every troubleshooting *including StackOverflow and [Heroku documentations](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline#debug-output).

Tried to precompile all assets locally `bundle exec rails_env=production rake assets:precompile`

Added `config.serve_static_assets = true` in application.rb, also tried `config.serve_static_files = true`

Tried `gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production`

And other things, still didn't work. The website loads, without any assets, javascript or styles. The browser console gives this warning:

> Loading failed for the  with source “...
>   /assets/application-c2decc28eb82aba39474d1a38f2cc1f016634981895dfbe9cb87ebb12709630d.js”.

I have know idea of what can be. Is Heroku looking for assets somewhere else? How can I check it and fix it? It was working yesterday, but don't know what is causing this issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using ?

Comment: Version 5.1.6 ...

Comment: `config.serve_static_assets = true` and `gem 'rails_12factor'` are not needed anymore  on Heroku (if you are dealing with a brand new app at least). Also, you don't  need to precompile anything locally and I actually recommend removing all precompiled assets. `rails assets:clobber` should clear everything.  How do  you include your assets in the layout, by the way?

Comment: Why are you precompiling locally? That should only need to happen in production. As mentioned, neither of those things are needed on Heroku anymore, and they won't affect your local setup. But to answer your question, is the application starting in production as well?

Comment: Ok guys, thanks to your advices, I've ran the app locally on "production" mode, and the assets didn't load also. So the problem is the production configurations. When I get some time I'm gonna check the rb files..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my `environments/production.rb` file.
This config was pointing to another host. Now fixed.

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://yourhost.herokuapp.com/"
```